# how to get network bytes sent /received values specific to every MAC address

Tags: wmi

I have a problem in which I have to figure out how many network bytes are sent / received through every interface. This data is to be known for interfaces that have a valid mac address.

Step 1: I will obtain set of valid interfaces with mac address from win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class using "where ipenabled = true" condition.

Step 2: I then need to find bytessentpersec, currentbandwith etc. For this I can use Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface but this has no field that is common with any of the fields of the above class to associate these values to a macaddress. Even though the name and description fields of both class see

Please help to resolve this issue. Is there any kind of option to solve this?

Regards,
Sudarshan

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft IP Helper Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366071.aspx)